# How to get PID of process by name?

Tags: d

I need to get PID of process by it's name. I looked at [docs](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_process.html#.Pid), but it's seems that I can get PID only if I am manually call process with `spawn()`

For example I need to get PID of already working FireFox.

I am writing tiny app for monitoring micro-services. Only one service can working at one time.

Comment: You do it the same way you would in C. And there's potentially many PIDs with the same name (even what the user sees as a single program can have several pids). What do you intend to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process has no name, so it is not possible to find PID by searching for some string that may or may not represent a name. What process does have is the *command* that is used when was fork()ed. So the "name" you see when you use `ps` is actually *argv[0]*, and as Adam pointed out, you may have hundreds of processes with the same command...

It is possible to give a name to the thread using [pthread_setname()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html). In D set/get the thread name is done using the [Thread.name property](https://dlang.org/library/core/thread/thread.name.html). Problem is that in most cases developers do not set the thread name...

You can grab a list of running processes by implementing something like readproc (http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/proc/readproc.c?view=markup) and then sarching for the process you need PID of, but that is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: What you're saying is not entirely true, at least for Windows. See the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx Porting that to D should be fairly easy. -- For Linux etc. idk if there's anything equivalent.